# What are good all-round core exercises

Tags: abdominals, core, strength-gain

So after a dieting period I'm switching back to eating healthy but in larger quantities (bulking).

What would be good all-round exercises to do all week round?

I work out 4 days a week so could I do the same exercises everyday and still train most of my core muscles? I'm still doing 'regular' fitness (weights) but also cardio combined with my core exercises so its not purely core.

What would be good core exercises to do both in the gym and at home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some of my "conditioning" exercises, mainly around "core".

- [Seated medicine ball tosses](http://exrx.net/Plyometrics/MBSeatedSideThrow.html). I keep my heels off the ground, legs bent. If I don't have my buddy I toss against the wall maybe ~3 feet away.
- [Barbell cleans](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/Clean.html). Not too heavy, something I'm comfortable doing reps of 8.
- [Medicine ball sit up toss](http://exrx.net/Plyometrics/MBSitUpWall.html).
- [Bicycle crunches](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-Bicycle-Crunches).
- On the rings, [front and back levers](http://www.beastskills.com/tutorial/the-levers/). These take a while to work up to, but levers are a terrific skillset given the minimal equipment required coupled with the strength gains.
- [Flutter kicks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calisthenics). No idea if it really works my abs but they hurt like heck and my [psoas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psoas_major_muscle) is pretty well fried, and I consider my psoas to be married to my hips and back.

Planks are cool but I find them pretty boring, and isometrically I'd rather do front squats (including as part of the clean).

Comment: I totally share your opinion on the planks, i dont 'mind' doing any exercise but planks are pretty boring. Great answer though, thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Front planks, side planks, rollouts w/stability ball, barbell or wheel, jackknifes w/stability ball, pikes with stability ball, front plank/stir the pot on stability ball.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? The poster may not know what planks, jackknifes or even stability balls are.

Comment: i know what those exercises are but a future visitor with the same question might not. Either way thanks for the answer.